# Ruby on Rails and Mongoid are driving me nuts! Few simple questions about querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database

I am trying to retrieve all "cards" from Mongoid that have request="preview"

I'm doing this via:

```
  @preview_cards = Card.where("request" => "PREVIEW")
```

I have a few questions.

1) Why can't I do?

```
  @preview_cards = Card.find_by_request("PREVIEW")
```

I get an error: undefined method `find_by_request' for Card:Class

2) Once I have the cards in the @preview_cards variable, I can't iterate through them. For example:

```
@preview_cards.each do |c| c.fullname end
```

simply just returns the object id `#<Mongoid::Criteria:0x103eaf778>`

3) Is there an "all" method you can call instead of first and last. For example, this works:

```
@preview_cards.first.fullname
```

but i want to be able to iterate through each "row" in mongo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No schema, so no automagic method generation. You can create your own helpers, though.

Are you sure? That works fine for me. What's returned is different than what happens once you try iterating. For example:

```
[19] pry(main)> ts = FooDoc.where("name" => "ohai")
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"name"=>"ohai"},
  options:  {},
  class:    FooDoc,
  embedded: false>

[20] pry(main)> ts.each { |t| p t.name }
"ohai"
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"name"=>"ohai"},
  options:  {},
  class:    FooDoc,
  embedded: false>
```

For getting all, use `all`:

```
Card.all(conditions: { request: "PREVIEW" })
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the "automagic method generation" -- I'm very much used to no framework PHP, and can't tell when things are supposed to be magical and not. Also, the "conditions" with all method threw an error.. maybe something weird I'm doing. In any case the each did work correctly, so I will use that. Thank you.

Comment: @BrianW No problem; I used Ruby 1.9 syntax--are you on 1.8? If so, use the old hash syntax.